# Xamarin.Forms - Expand Width of Column To Longest Content

Tags: uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, column-width

In Xamarin Forms, I want to create a 2-column table where the first column expands to the width of the cell with the longest content, like:

[image]

What's the best way to accomplish this in Xamarin.Forms?

Answer (score 3):

Make the first column 'auto' and the second '*'. According to the docs auto should be the size of its children and * will take the remaining space.

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />      
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```